# ImageJ failed to getCurrentImage

Tags: java, imagej

I am using IJ library in Java. I have opened several images and I would like to save the last active image. However, I only manage to save last opened image instead of last active image. Any solution?

```
ImagePlus imp = new ImagePlus(path);
imp.show();

JButton btnTest = new JButton("Test");
btnTest.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        ImagePlus img = WindowManager.getCurrentImage();
        FileSaver fs = new FileSaver(img);
        fs.saveAsTiff();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

not exactly sure what you mean but when you open an image that becomes the active image. you could use WindowManager.putBehind() to select the previous image. Otherwise you could use WindowManager.getImageTitles to get the names of all the images open and then select them specifically for saving. hope this helps :-)